# Upgrade C2 to C3 Uncaught TypeError involving Dotenv

Tags: upgrades, environments

I am just trying to upgrade and get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::__construct() must be an instance of Dotenv\Loader, string given called in (…) /html/index.php on line 17 (…)
```

Which is completely new to me. Never happened before and my setup is pretty standard. Is this a hosting Problem? Can’t make anythiong of it.

Craft version seems to be 3.3.4 according to the name of the zip (Craft-3.3.4.1.zip).

Answer (score 1):

Using a earlier version of Craft (3.3.3) solved the problem. Updating from there was shaky but eventually worked.